# Do 気が付く{つく} and 気[付く]{づく} have the same meaning?

Tags: word-choice, nuances, verbs

Do 気が付く{つく} and 気[付く]{づく} have the same meaning?

If they both mean the same, is the が optional?

Comment: It appears that they do have the same meaning. Maybe this is no different than any other case of particle deletion?

Answer (score 6):

気が付く has three meanings.

1. notice, realize
2. (often in the form よく気が付く) be attentive, be quick to notice
3. come to oneself (usually after losing consciousness)

For senses 1 and 3, 気付く is also used. When used in these senses, I do not think that there is any difference in meaning between 気が付く and 気付く. I do not recognize any difference in formality, either, but I may be wrong.

Comment: It surprises me to hear that 気付く is used in sense 3. I will have to keep my eyes/ears open for that one.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, they mean the same thing.  The one with `が` seems slightly more formal.

**Edit**: Apparently this is ungrammatical, although I don't understand why.  Maybe I'll make it a separate topic.

<strike>It is also more likely to be used if there is some "long" clause that modifies the `気`.  Ex:</strike>

> 母に電話をかけなかった気がつきました　→　I realized I forgot to call my mother

Comment: Your example sentence is ungrammatical.

Comment: As far as I can tell, 気がつく cannot directly connect to a noun or verb phrase without a particle in between it. You would something like 忘れたことに気がついた。That being said, after looking through a collection of sample sentences, both with and without が, there doesn't seem to be a distinction relating to clause length. I'm unable to offer a better explanation right now, so I'll have to defer to someone else.

Comment: Actually, doesn't this prove that `気がつく` and `気付く` are **exactly** that same?  It seems the reason my example was ungrammatical (and another of my Japanese friends said this) is that `気がつく` is a set verb, not a noun+が+verb.  So you can't modify the 気 as I though because there's no noun actually in there.  Does that seem to follow logically?

Comment: I think 'prove' is too strong of a word. I don't think it can logically follow just from what has been said that they are *exactly* the same. Perhaps there is some factor (social, cultural, contextual, etc.) influencing their use. In this case, they would have the same meaning at a surface level, but could convey something about the speaker, the listener, and/or the situation. I have no idea whether this is the case, especially since all the examples we have exist (mostly) outside of a context.

Comment: Indeed `気がつく` is an idiomatic phrase as istrasci points out, but that is not the reason it cannot be modified. It simply does not make sense to do it. The meaning of `気` relevant here is something like 'spiritual energy flow'. `母に電話をかけなかった気` would mean 'the spiritual energy flow that I did not call my mother'.